# Flutter: Why is this provider variable showing empty in one dart file but filled in another?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-provider

I'm using the `provider` package in Flutter to store some global variables. One of those variables is the user's Firebase `uid`. In my auth.dart file, I set up a stream to look at authentication state changes and use that to update the global `uid` variable. When I print from this file, it prints out the value correctly. However, when I then print from screenHome.dart, the value is empty. Why is this?

**auth.dart:**

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final globals = GlobalsProvider();

  UserModel.ModelUser? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {

    if (user != null) {
      globals.currentUID = user?.uid ?? ''; 
      return UserModel.ModelUser(uid: user.uid, username: '');
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Stream<UserModel.ModelUser?> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges()
      .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  ...
}
```

**screenHome.dart:**

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final globals = GlobalsProvider();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialize();
  }

  void initialize() async {
    if (kDebugMode) {print('currentUID: ${globals.currentUID}');}
    if (kDebugMode) {print('currentUsername: ${globals.currentUsername}');}

    ...
  }

}
```

**main.dart:**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseHelper.init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<GlobalsProvider>(
      create: (context) => GlobalsProvider(),
      child: Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(
        builder: (context, globalsProvider, child) => StreamProvider<ModelUser?>.value(
          value: AuthService().user,
          initialData: null,
          child: const GetMaterialApp(
            title: 'AppName',
            home: Wrapper(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**globalsProvider.dart:**

```
class GlobalsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String currentUID = '';
  ...
}
```